# Help understanding step in the proof of Taylor's theorem with remainder

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_{0},x\in A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy that $f^{(j)}$ exists and is continuous on the closed interval between $x_{0}$ and $x$ and differentiable on the open interval between $x_{0}$ and $x$ for all $j\leq k$. Then there exists a $c$ between $x_{0}$ and $x$, such that:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(j)}(x_{0})}{j!}(x-x_{0})^{j}+\frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!}(x-x_{0})^{k+1}.\quad\quad (*)
\end{equation}

**My question**: How does one realise that $(*)$ has exactly one solution $M\in\mathbb{R}$ when $x\neq x_{0}$:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(j)}(x_{0})}{j!}(x-x_{0})^{j}+M(x-x_{0})^{k+1}
\end{equation}
Is it because $(*)$ is a linear function or? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \ne x_0$,we have

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)-\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(j)}(x_{0})}{j!}(x-x_{0})^{j}}{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}=M
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I'm not understanding is the intuition behind why one can say that there exists exactly one solution to $(*)$. :)

Comment: Suppose, that you have the equation $a=c+Mb$ with $ b \ne 0.$. Then $ \frac{a-c}{b}=M.$